# Using ActiveX in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to embed ActiveX into html, and to call the function from javascript

```
<html>
<head>
    <TITLE>NVPlayer</TITLE> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <OBJECT   
        ID="NVPLayerCompX"  
        NAME="NVPLayerCompX"
        CLASSID="clsid:320F09DC-6C26-4C18-BCA1-54030E7145B7"  
        CODEBASE="NVPlayerCompX.dll"  
        WIDTH="300"  
        HEIGHT="300">  
    </OBJECT>       
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:launch()">Click me!</button>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function launch()
        {
             var myObject = document.getElementById("NVPLayerCompX").object

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

i am getting null in myObject, do i need to use ActiveXObject?
i am new with this issues, what is the meaning of the name property in the object element

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myObject = document.getElementById("NVPLayerCompX")
```

That is your object

Comment: thanks, how can i create the sub classes under this object , is there any blog or something which explain it?